# Car no longer starts, behaved weird before giving up

Tags: electrical, battery

This is a ten year old diesel car from Ford, the Ford Focus DA1.

Let me start with the chain of events:

Car has been standing outdoors for two weeks without use, had been almost frozen but not quite below zero. Girlfriend turns it on, starts fine and she blasts the warm air to clear up fog on windshield. She starts driving, and suddenly the ABS and anti skid lights come on. She parks it and starts checking the service manual, turning the engine off. The car had been running for maybe five minutes. Electronics don’t work at all - no dash lights, nothing.

She calls her parents, they come with their car and hook up starter cables. The electronics now go on, but starter won’t turn the engine. She notes that there is light smoke coming off the cables. As the ignition key is turned to starter, the electronics “flicker” which I think is normal.

It was quite cold out at this time, about 4-6 degrees celsius.

One explanation is that somehow the battery had been almost completely drained, and her use and quick turn off was too much. But then the starter cables should have been enough to start the engine turning; it being a diesel engine it should be enough to get it turning to keep it rolling? But no dice.

I am now at a loss for what to do, I was not there so couldn’t try roll starting it or check the fuses. I’m going to check it later today with a multimeter in hand.

What else should I do to diagnose this issue? It kinda sounds like something is short circuited. Someone said online that  if the fuses aren’t covered properly moisture can get into the ESP or ECU and cause corrosion and eventually shorting.

It had been really humid the last couple of weeks.

Please any help would be appreciated, I really need this car to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may just have a bad connection on the battery posts.  This would account for the sudden loss of power and also explain why everything powered up once the jump leads were added.

Try disconnecting the battery connections and cleaning the connectors and battery post with some sand paper or wire wool, then reconnect.

The reason why the car would not start using the jump leads and also why there was smoke will be due to the jump leads being too thin (cheap) for the job.  The jump leads wont be able to carry the high current required by the starter - possibly 100 Amps. Those type of jump leads are really only good for charging a flat battery, you need to leave them connected for 5-10 minutes before trying to start the car.  Jump leads capable of immediately starting a car are a lot thicker and also expensive.

The only other possibility I can think of from your description is that the battery has gone open circuit internally, which would mean getting a new battery

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I really hope it’s this easy, and I guess the voltmeter would show the voltage to be nominal if so. Do you think there could be other causes? It seems strange that the low power circuits would stop getting any power if it’s just bad connectivity.

Comment: From your description, the only other possibility I can think of is that the battery has gone open circuit internally, which would mean getting a new battery.  It is very possible for oxide on the battery post/connectors to totally disconnect the battery.

Comment: Did you connect the jump leads directly to the battery posts?

Comment: The battery does not have any charge basically, about one volt on the meter. Is the battery just dead? Why would it die suddenly like this?

Comment: Internal corrosion can cause failure of the conductors inside the battery.  It is just one of the ways a battery can die.  Sounds like you need a new battery.

Comment: Ah chucks, the battery is really stuck in there. Need some hollow M10 hex wrench, have to get to a nut axially. Sigh. So you think it’s just corrosion inside the battery then? Not any other electrical fault? Hope you’re right, will have to try again tomorrow.

Comment: In your description, did the smoke from the cables start before attempting to start the car?  The reason I ask is that if the starter was  stuck on for some reason, it could have drawn a lot of current while the car was being driven, which would have flattened the battery and killed it.    If you get another battery, touch the connectors on briefly to verify that the starter doesn’t start turning immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I’m hesitant to connect the new battery at all as there is continuity between the positive and negative connector inside the car. Is that normal? The car is off. The resistance reads near zero. The old battery, after being disconnected for the night, has gained voltage, suggesting a short was draining it. What do?

Comment: I don't think you can come to any conclusion about the continuity or the battery voltage increasing.  I would suggest that you either try charging the old battery (but it is likely badly damaged now) or getting a new battery.   Connect the positive terminal correctly and then just briefly touch the negative terminal to the battery to see what happens.  A small spark is expected, but anything more should be investigated.

Comment: I connected the battery, and it sparked as if there was a sudden discharge - both when connecting and disconnecting. Maybe normal but to me suggests something is shorted. I did smell something strange, but that could well have been the welding from the battery terminal. I also disconnected the wire harness from the fuse box but the two battery connectors were still shorted...

Comment: Was the battery fully charged?  You would expect a small spark when connecting and even more so when disconnecting.  If you are not happy, you need to get someone qualified to look at it.

Comment: Again thank you so much  I forgot to say this is a new battery, so I suppose that should be alright. I’ll just connect the battery and assume it was the matter of a bad battery like you suggested. The engine turns on fine with this battery.

Comment: I am pleased you got it working.

Comment: Actually I think there’s something wrong with the alternator. It was too hot to touch even though the engine hadn’t been turning in the last fifteen minutes...

Comment: Looks like you have found your problem.  I would disconnect the battery before it totally discharges and damages it.  The diode pack in the alternator may well have become faulty.